# I've started to make dairy free cheese for cafes but have problem scaling up?

Tags: sauce

I've started making dairy free cheese for cafes. Similar to whisking a sauce for 5 minutes. Ive tried scaling up using a bamix stick blender with large Raymond Blanc non stick pot on induction cooker this leads to problems with grey flex appearing in the cheese? Any advise much appreciated.

Comment: If you're having trouble scaling up a recipe, it will help to include the recipe you're using and the procedure you use (edit them into the question).  Its easier to see what might be going wrong with more information.  I admit I'm pretty confused as to what you're asking, without more context.

Comment: Yep, there are 100s of different recipes/methods for making various dairy free cheeses.

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that the blades on the bamix stick blender are contacting the interior of the pot occasionally and scratching some of the non-stick coating off, and that's the grey flecks you see in your cheese.

Comment: This seems very likely - A whisk would be unlikely to chew up the non-stick coating - a toothed blender like that would. Perhaps you need to find a powered whisk, if it's whisking you want, or a heat source that works with a commercial stand mixer and whisk.